# individual table for user activity or single select query

Tags: mysql, social-networking

I am creating a social network for my client where they need facebook-like wall and user recent activity.

I have around 8 table says user account , info , groups , comments , page , photogallery, likes , shares.

In the `user profile`, they need the entire activity of the user in the site.

Can I use a single **Join Query** or need to have a **individual table as recentactivity**.

Comment: show the kind of join you are doing

Comment: i have not yet started i am asking user , what shall i do for that?

Comment: it all depends on how the tables are related

Answer (score 1):

You could have a union query to pull data from the different tables and store in a view.  Here's the general idea...

```
create view 'v_recent_activity' as 
select user_id, 'comment' as action, comment_text as action_info, comment_date as action_date from comments
union
select user_id, 'photo' as action, photo_url as action_info, photo_date as action_date from photos
union
select user_id, 'page' as action, page_url as action_info, comment_date as action_date from pages
union
select user_id, 'likes' as action, like_info as action_info, comment_date as action_date from likes
union
select user_id, 'shares' as action, share_info as action_info, share_date as action_date from shares
```

Then you could access it with something like

```
Select * from v_recent_activity where action_date between <begin_date> and <end_date>
```

or with a join

```
Select a.*, b.* from users a join v_recent_activity b on a.id = b.user_id where a.id = <user_id> and b.action_date between <begin_date> and <end_date>
```

Comment: i think this view doesn't work because i need it in real time.

Comment: Views are real-time. They are essentially "stored queries" which can be accessed as a table.  They always operate on live data.  If you need to dynamically create the query to include/exclude certain tables, you could still use the view and alter the where `action = <action>`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a `log` or `activity` table that would contain the record of their recent activity.  This way you only need a single query.  You would join the other tables based on the activity type.